# gcc for ARM does a compare with zero after a subtraction

Tags: assembly, gcc, arm, cortex-m

I am currently trying to check, what C code does generate the best/efficient code for ARM Cortex-M processors. Especially for loops: I wanted to know how I need to write a loop to be able to omit any compare statements in assembly and make use of the Zero flag.

For that, I set up a demo project with a loop. The loop counts down to zero, as seen here:

```
sum = 0;

    for(int i=ADC_BUFFER_LENGTH-1; i!=0; i--)
    {
      sum += adc_data_buffer[i];
    }
```

The disassembly of the code did among other things:

```
...
3b01        subs    r3, #1
2b00        cmp     r3, #0
d1f5        bne.n   14 <main+0x14>
...
```

As one can see, the counter value in the register 3 will be decremented, then compared to "0" and it will branch if it is not equal (= Zero-flag is not set).

The usage for the compare statement here puzzles me greatly as the subtraction statement also has an influence on the Zero-flag of course.

It is compiled with the -Og optimization option. When I used -O3, then the subtraction did not occur right before the branch and so it needed a compare for that. As the register 3 is not used anywhere else, the assembly could even be further optimized by rearranging the statements a little.

It puzzles me because I have read multiple times that the optimizer/compiler now days is so good, it is not possible to be better by writing you own assembly... Can somebody shed some light on this?

The target is a STM32F030, compiled with arm-none-eabi-gcc 10.3.1-2.3.1 on Windows 10 (STM32-for-VSCode)

Comment: Do not expect optimal code when compiling with `-Og`.  This optimisation level optimises for a debugging experience, so it'll avoid optimisations that eliminate parts of the computation.

Comment: With 32-bit instruction bus, this gives you 2 instructions. Some of the optimization can be targeting reducing the number for code branches and cramming the meat of the loop code in less 32-bit words.

Comment: gcc's output has not gotten better since 4.x.x, some improvements but as we see on SO many failures.  Even with "great" optimization, it is still expected that one could make improvements by hand for a decent sized project.  One should be able to find some improvements.  Good/bad though is relative.   This is possibly intentional for optimizing for debug since debug wants to make a binary that you can single step, etc, and as a result, one would not be surprised by something like this.

Comment: Could you mention CFLAGS and gcc version so that people can play with this in compiler explorer?

Answer (score 0):

1. If this code should add all the values from the buffer - then it is invalid as it skips the `adc_data_buffer[0]` (`ADC_BUFFER_LENGTH` defined as `16`)

```
    for(int i=ADC_BUFFER_LENGTH-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
      sum += adc_data_buffer[i];
    }
```

Optimized for the size or `-O2`.

```
foo:
        movs    r2, r0
        movs    r3, r0
        movs    r0, #0
        adds    r2, r2, #60
.L2:
        ldr     r1, [r2]
        adds    r0, r0, r1
        movs    r1, r2
        subs    r2, r2, #4
        cmp     r3, r1
        bne     .L2
        bx      lr   lr
```

To be more correct you should use `size_t` instead of `int` for indexes.

```
    for(size_t i=ADC_BUFFER_LENGTH; i; i--)
    {
      sum += adc_data_buffer[i - 1];
    }
```

(it will compile to the same code as above)

`-O3` optimization will simply unroll the loop

https://godbolt.org/z/nGEehro5h